# code / decode Huffman Tree Haskell

Tags: haskell, huffman-code

I asked a questions earlier on how to make a tree, but now I am stuck again. 
I want to code and decode my Huffmann Tree

So these are my types:

```
module Types where


type Occurence  = (Number, Value)
type Occurences = [Occurence]
type Number     = Int
type Value      = Char
type Code       = [Directions]
type CodeTable  = [(Value, Code)]


data Directions = L | R deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)


data HTree      = Leaf {frequency :: Number, character:: Value} |
                  Node {frequency:: Number, 
                        leftChild:: HTree,
                        rightChild:: HTree} deriving Show

makeLeaf :: Occurence -> HTree
makeLeaf (n, c) = Leaf n c
```

These are the functions that I have already written and those are actually working:

```
makeTree :: Occurences -> HTree
makeTree = makeCodes . toTreeList

toTreeList :: Occurences -> [HTree]
toTreeList = map (uncurry Leaf)

h :: [HTree] -> [HTree]
h (t1:t2:ts) = insertTree (join t1 t2) ts

makeCodes :: [HTree] -> HTree
makeCodes [t] = t
makeCodes ts = makeCodes (h ts)

join :: HTree -> HTree -> HTree
join t1 t2 = Node (freq1+freq2) t1 t2
    where
      freq1 = v t1
      freq2 = v t2

v :: HTree -> Int
v (Leaf n _ ) = n
v (Node n _ _) = n

insertTree :: HTree -> [HTree] -> [HTree]
insertTree t [] = [t]
insertTree t (t1:ts) 
     | v t < v t1 = t:t1:ts
     | otherwise = t1 : insertTree t ts




constructTable :: HTree -> CodeTable
constructTable = convert []
      where
      convert :: Code -> HTree -> CodeTable
      convert hc (Leaf n c) = [(c, hc)]
      convert hc (Node n tl tr) = (convert (hc++[L]) tl) ++ (convert (hc++[R]) tr)
```

Now I want to code an decode...

```
code :: String -> (Code, CodeTable)

decode :: Code -> CodeTable -> String
decode code table = undefined
```

I usually would approach this kinda this way

```
code :: HTree -> Char -> String
code (Leaf c n) x
| c==x = []
| otherwise = error "!!"
code (Node li n re) x
| member x li = ’L’:code li x
| otherwise = ’R’:code re x
where member a (Leaf c n) = (a==c)
member a (Node li c re) = (member a li) || (member a re)
```

But how do I do this using CodeTable?

Answer (score 0):

Well you know how to make a tree when you know occurrences so I suppose you should work out how to make occurrences out of a string.

```
import Data.Map as M
frequencyTable :: String -> Occurrences
frequencyTable = sort . map (uncurry flip) . M.toList . M.fromListWith (+) . map (\x -> (x,1))
```

And so now you can make the Huffman codes for a string:

```
codeTable : String -> CodeTable
codeTable = constructTable . makeTree . frequencyTable
```

And you know how to encode a string when you have the Huffman codes:

```
code1 [] char = error “not in code table”
code1 ((c1,code)::table) char
  | c1 == char = code
  | otherwise = code1 table char
code s = (s >>= code1 table, table) where
  table = codeTable s
```

Decoding is a bit more fiddly and you probably want to convert from the code table into a tree so that you can decide in a straightforward way.